# Multiple rails resource routes split across scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im having some issues trying to split up a controller based on scope.

My code looks like this

```
  scope '/admin' do
    resources :pages, only: [:index, :create, :new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  end

  resources :pages, only: [:show]
```

Ideally, Id just like to have the show page not behind the admin scope, however when I call `page_path(1)`, it routes to `/admin/pages/1`, not `/pages/1`.

What is the easiest way to work around this issue?

Thanks

---

Updated with routes

```
pages_path  GET /admin/pages(.:format)  pages#index
POST    /admin/pages(.:format)  pages#create
new_page_path   GET /admin/pages/new(.:format)  pages#new
edit_page_path  GET /admin/pages/:id/edit(.:format) pages#edit
page_path   PATCH   /admin/pages/:id(.:format)  pages#update
PUT /admin/pages/:id(.:format)  pages#update
DELETE  /admin/pages/:id(.:format)  pages#destroy
GET /pages/:id(.:format)    pages#show
root_path   GET /   pages#main
```

And view:

```
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
    <%= link_to page.title, page_path(page) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: copy view code where you are writing this page_path(1)

Comment: updated original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To influence route helper names, use `as`-parameter:

```
scope '/admin', as: 'admin' do
```

However, it makes sense to place the admin's controller in `Admin` namespace, so you can do this:

```
namespace 'admin' do
```

That will influence path (`/admin`), route helpers (`admin_`) and controller namespace (`Admin::PagesController`). A separate controller allows for easier access and layout control. Also, you can make a separate `show` for admins, which is nice to have.

Of course, in your forms you'll have to use constructs like `form_for [:admin, @page]`, or `form_for @page, url: admin_page_path(@page)`.

Comment: but previously routes are generated without 'admin_'.

Comment: @user123 your route definitions clash: `page_path` is defined in `admin` scope first, then you accidentally reuse it in the next `resources` definition, while the route helper is not overwritten. The cleanest solution I can imagine is prefix admin-specific routes so they don't clash.

Comment: thanks heaps for your help, namespacing admin is definitely the smarter option. thanks for your help D-side and @user123

Comment: Gosh, I've confused @user123 with OP. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
  scope '/admin', as: 'admin' do
      resources :pages, only: [:index, :create, :new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  end
  resources :pages, only: [:show]
```

Just do the changes as above

Comment: This works, however when updating I get 'No route matches [PATCH] "/pages/2"'

Comment: when submitting a form to update a page entry. update obv wont get thru

Comment: Routes here still clash, it's just the opposite way now :D `show`, `update` and `destroy` use the same paths, but route helpers don't duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope module: '/admin' do
  resources :pages, only: [:index, :create, :new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```